# No two children may sit in adjacent seats

Tags: combinatorics

There are twelve people which includes 3 couples, 3 single adults and 3 children. In how many ways they can be arranged :-
a) if no two children can sit in adjacent seats?
b) if each couple must sit in adjacent seats?

Comment: for a) try to find arrangements of 9 elements instead of 12, because 3 of them are acually couples of a child and a random person from the rest, b) same thing just the couples are not random.

Comment: I got this idea by watching other question on stack but still not able to find the answer.

Comment: can you try at least ?

Comment: Yes i m trying from previous two hours :(

Comment: Are these separate questions?  If so, you should read the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117281/given-5-children-and-8-adults-how-many-ways-can-they-be-seated-so-that-there-ar?rq=1), which will help you with the first question.

Comment: This is one statement and then there are two questions arises from that statement. I can solve easily if there are two groups( men ,women) or (children, adults) but there are three ( couples,adults, children )so i am not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $9! \cdot 10C3 \cdot 3!$

b) $9! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!$

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: I know that , I confirmed it from professor.
But I am still confused how i got answer of b part

Comment: Treat each couple as a single object.  Then you have nine objects to arrange, the three couples, the three single adults, and the three children.  You can arrange the objects in $9!$ ways.  Each of the three couples can be arranged internally in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are $9! \cdot 2!^3$ arrangements in which the couples sit in adjacent seats.