# Different ways students can be assigned to supervisor?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $40$ students who must be assigned to $4$ supervisors. And each supervisor must have at least $8$ students, then how many ways students can be assigned?

I tried a lot but not able to think about it, it is **not a homework** problem. I am taking combinatorics in fall, so I started studying on my own.

Comment: For problems like this it is important to specify details.  Are the students distinguishable from one another?  Are the supervisors?  Suppose I have three students and two supervisors and require that each supervisor have at least one student.    What is the answer then?

Comment: This is an unfortunately tedious problem.  I see little way around this beyond finding all of the different ways of distributing the amount of students to each advisor and then for each such way of distributing the amounts count how many ways the students could be assigned in those amounts.  For example, you could have them split up as $8,8,10,14$ where the first supervisor gets eight, the second gets eight, the third gets 10 etc... which the students could be assigned in that fashion in $\binom{40}{8,8,10,14}=\frac{40!}{8!8!10!14!}$ number of ways.

Comment: @Daugmented you will overcount doing it like that.

Comment: Yep, sorry, that true...

Comment: @JMoravitz , third supervisor can also be assigned with 8 students and 4th with 16. Can you explain it little more

Comment: Yes, and it could be $(8,9,11,12)$ and it could be $(11,9,8,12)$ and it could be $(16,8,8,8)$ etc... like I said... it is an *incredibly* tedious approach.  The approach I describe is again, you go through and you list out all $\binom{11}{3}$ different ways to have the *amounts* of students distributed among the supervisors, and then for each of those ways find the number of ways of actually distributing the students in that fashion, and add all of these together.

Comment: @lulu  , yes they will be distinguishable (students and supervisors)

Comment: You can use generating functions to get a solution.  However, this is more-or-less taking JMoravitz's approach in disguise - not sure how much faster you can compute it.

Comment: If everyone is distinguishable then it is a very tedious problem indeed.  Maybe Inclusion-Exclusion is feasible, though I am inclined to doubt it.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion would still require you to keep track of the number of ways in which one or more supervisors gets $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,$ or $7$ students.  At a glance, it appears just as if not more tedious than doing it directly.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Oh, agreed.  My guess is that there is no way to avoid some grueling listing of scenarios.

Comment: @JMoravitz , one of my friend told me its 15C4 * 11C4 * 7C4 . Is this correct?

Comment: Very definitely not.  $\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{11}{4}\cdot\binom{7}{4}\approx 1.5\cdot 10^7$.  This is far less than $\binom{40}{10,10,10,10}\approx 4.7\cdot 10^{21}$, the latter number being the number of ways in which the students can be distributed among the supervisors so that the supervisors get exactly ten students each, which is only a small subset of the possible ways to distribute the students satisfying that each supervisor gets at least eight students each.  The correct final answer should be somewhere on the order of $10^{23}$ or $10^{24}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz , then I think I need to wait until Fall to ask from professor

Comment: Whether this is a homework problem or not, is not the point or the issue.  You state emphatically that it is **not** a homework problem.  All good and well, but your question is written like you copied it from a text book.  Where is your input?  Your take on the problem.  We object to problem statement questions (written as though reading an imperative from an assigned text exercise),

Comment: Were you preparing a year in advance for your Fall 2018 combinatorics class when you posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549594/no-two-children-may-sit-in-adjacent-seats) 5 months ago?

Comment: @amWhy , I am following few books to grasp content. this is not a exercise question otherwise I would have had solution.

Comment: I would cry if this question was straight copied from a textbook.  It sounds like the OP might have seen a similarly worded problem and changed the wording slightly or tweaked the numbers in such a way that it had terrible consequences and the total number of arrangements exploded into obscene numbers.  The question where each supervisor has at least one student is easy in comparison.  The question where students are indistinguishable is also quite easy.

Comment: What you asked is an exercise, Randhawa, and you showed absolutely no work or thinking on your part, in the post.  You assigned us, in effect, a problem to solve *for you*.

Comment: @amWhy , the question you are pointing is from Discrete Mathematics took last fall. which had two lectures on permutation and combination

Comment: @JMoravitz , It is not from book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a generating function approach here.  That is, you let $x$ be an indeterminate and find the $40!$ times the coefficient of $x^{40}$ in $$\left(\frac{x^8}{8!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{16}}{16!}\right)^4.$$

The reason this works is that when you expand the product in all possible ways,  factoring out a factorial of the degree, each product has a multinomial coefficient.  For example, taking $$\frac{x^{11}}{11!} \frac{x^9}{9!} \frac{x^8}{8!}  \frac{x^{12}}{12!} =  \frac{40!}{11!\, 9!\, 8!\, 12!}\frac{x^{40}}{40!} $$ and multiplying by $40!$ gives the coefficient $$\frac{40!}{11!\, 9!\, 8!\, 12!}$$ which is the number of ways of choosing groups where the first supervisor has $8$ students, the second supervisor has $9$ students, etc.  You only have to go up to degree $16$ in each factor because no group can have more than $16$ people.

Of course, expanding this out completely is equivalent to adding up all the possible multinomials corresponding to how many students each supervisor takes as JMoravitz mentions.  But software packages like Sage are optimized to do this kind of convolution pretty quickly.

Edit: In Sage,

```
p = sum([x^n / factorial(n) for n in range(8, 17)])
q = (p^4).expand()
print q.coefficient(x,40) * factorial(40)
```

prints $435451605680654896510320$.

Comment: This one looks correct. As I am satisfied with solution, So, accepting as an answer but I will add some opinions in Fall, if I had.