# Simple Permutations/Combinations Question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A group of 5 men and 5 women stand in line to have their photo taken.

How many ways can they stand in line if no two men and no two women stand together?

My method: _M_M_M_M_M_

Male * Female = 5P5 * 6P5 = 86400

Correct Answer = 5! * 5! * 2 = 28800

I don't understand why I got it wrong, can anyone help please?

Comment: Why do you have 6 $_$s?

Comment: They are the spaces for the women, I used the logic of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-many-ways-are-there-for-8-men-and-5-women-to-stand-in-a-line-so-that-no-two

Comment: right, but you have 6 of them and only 5 women

Comment: Yes, so that's why I put 6P5, arranging 5 women in 6 spaces. Is that correct?

Comment: No it is not. Here **neither** men nor women can be neighbours. In the other question, men could be neighbours (and, given the numbers, some had to be).

Comment: Sorry I dont understand that... Isn't my method going to separate all of them so they are arranged alternately?

Comment: @André OP's reasoning makes sure both men and women are not neighbors. (It's invalid for another reason...)

Comment: Definitely not. If you assign a woman to the leftmost $3$ spaces, and to the rightmost $2$, a couple of men around the middle will be next to each other.

Comment: Oh... I see why my method is wrong now. Can you explain how the solution works?

Comment: Order the five women, order the five men, then decide whether the seats start with a man or women and interlace them. (5! x 5! x 2) @Andre Ah, duh.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that you could do that... I think I get some of it now... Is there a more 'graphical' solution? :)

Comment: @blue: Thank you for informing me of a way to solve the problem. I might have floundered helplessly otherwise. For days.

Comment: @André Sorry, I should have phrased it in the form of a hint to the OP, I know. (e.g. "Count the ways depending on whether a man or woman sits first.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you distiguish only by man and woman, then they can be arranged:
$$m-w-m-w-m-w-m-w-m-w$$ and $$w-m-w-m-w-m-w-m-w-m$$

If you distinguish the womans, there are $5!$ possibilities. The same for men.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. Maybe if the answer was (5!*5!)+(5!*5!) I could've guessed it earlier! :D

Comment: You are welcome. The main thing is, that you understand it now.